# PHPMailer IsHTML(true) not working

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send emails from PHPMailer. Everything is working but the problem is it is sending emails along with HTML tags even after writing `$mail->IsHTML(true);` . Below is my code for sending emails.

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = EMAIL_COMPOSE_SECURE; 
    $mail->Host = EMAIL_COMPOSE_SMTP_HOST;  
    $mail->Port = EMAIL_COMPOSE_PORT;
    $mail->Username = EMAIL_COMPOSE_OUTGOING_USERNAME;
    $mail->Password = EMAIL_COMPOSE_OUTGOING_PASSWORD;
    $mail->SetFrom(EMAIL_COMPOSE_INCOMING_USERNAME);
    $mail->Subject =$subject;

    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->AddAddress($email_to);
    if(!$mail->Send()){
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else{
      echo "Message has been sent";
    }
```

And one more thing I will mention, in my application text editor for writing the emails is ckeditor. Will that cause any problem? Please help.

Comment: Try setting the Body after calling IsHTML. Just a quick thing to try.

Comment: Post the code that creates the message please.

Comment: is there html in $message?

Comment: Assuming this is the actual source code: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php
`IsHtml` just sets the `ContentType`, which is echoed by the `Send()` method.

Comment: if nothing works just use this :p `$mail->Body =  html_entity_decode($Body);`

Comment: @Chris : have tried that also unfortunately didn't work

Comment: @user3739658 : I tried that but still not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why would you *not* expect it to use HTML if you call `IsHTML(true)`? That's how you tell PHPMailer to treat your message body as HTML! If you don't want HTML as the content type, call `IsHTML(false)`, or just don't call it at all since plain text is the default.

If you want both HTML and plain text, call `msgHTML($html)` instead and it will also handle the HTML->text conversion for you.

As Chris said, call `IsHTML` *before* setting `Body`.

And as Dagon said, if you put HTML in `$message`, it will send HTML...

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, it should be sending the HTML tags.  Check that the received email has the `Content-Type:` is `text/html`.

It has to send the HTML tags still for the client at the other side to be able to display it properly.  If the message contains HTML tags and you don't want the tags, then you want to call `IsHtml(false)` and you need to actually strip the HTML from the message.

Not all email clients can read HTML tags.  So if you're seeing the HTML it's either because your client can't render HTML, or that the `Content-Type:` is `text/plain`.