# PHPMailer failing to send HTML

Tags: php, html-email, phpmailer

I'm having this strange problem with PHPMailer occasionally sending content-type: text/plain rather than content-type: text/html. I have the isHTML method set to true but I'm still getting this problem. Any advice from someone who's run into this problem before? The sender is gmail. I couldn't use the XMailer method like it suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [PHPMailer IsHTML(true) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399943/phpmailer-ishtmltrue-not-working)

> As Chris said, call IsHTML before setting Body.